# Metaheuristics must read articles and new research fields

Tags: metaheuristics

Where can I find the fundamentals and the must read articles on metaheuristics? Additionally, what are the current research focal points and areas of interest in this field?

I'm dedicated to gaining a comprehensive understanding of the subject and have been exploring resources such as Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaheuristic#Contributions) and scholarly papers authored by renowned researchers on Google Scholar (https://scholar.google.com/citations?hl=en&view_op=search_authors&mauthors=label%3Ametaheuristics&btnG=). But I would also like to know from researchers from here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A significant amount of research (maybe too much?) these days goes into "evolutionary" metaheuristics, an area that I think traces back to the creation of genetic algorithms. You can find a list of some of the many, many evolutionary algorithms at the [Evolutionary Computation Bestiary](https://github.com/fcampelo/EC-Bestiary). I frequently wonder how many of these algorithms are basically the same thing with different names and differently phrase biological analogs.

Comment: Yes. I believe that is true for some of the algorithms that I implemented and especially because of the discussion made by Sörensen on Metaheuristics, the metaphor exposed (https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1111/itor.12001). 

I saw his discussion on what would be good finds in the area, but I would like if it have other discussions about it.

Answer (score 1):

Not research papers, but I think a good place to start is the “Handbook of metaheuristics”: https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4419-1665-5

It contains a number of contributed chapters on different metaheuristics.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. I think I made a poor question. I'm not initing my studies in the field, I already used this book to learn something about the heuristics that I implemented. So for now, what do you think I should do to do good quality research on the field?